# Is there a way to show products on frontend without indexing in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, reindex, index

I have 60 million products in my store so I want to show products on front-end without using

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex` command.

Is there a way to show products on front-end without indexing.

Comment: which version of magento you used ?

Comment: @Msquare thanks for your response i am using Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1

Comment: @Prits here is another way for that you can set programmatically indexer: reindex after saving product. So you can not require to run manually indexer

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the cache
Admin sidebar > System > Cache Management

[image: Magento Cache Management]